# How to use apache camel to read data from mysql table and write into another table

Tags: java, mysql, apache-camel

Guys I am using Apache Camel to read data from mysql table. I am successfully printing it on console. But according to my requirement I need to read the data from one mysql database, then filter it by using some condition and then insert the filtered data in another mysql database table. I am posting my code below..

```
public class camelJdbc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp";
        final String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp1";
        DataSource dataSource = setupDataSource(url);
        DataSource dataSource1 = setupDataSource1(url1);

        SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry() ;
        reg.put("myDataSource",dataSource);
        reg.put("myDataSource1",dataSource1);

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);
        context.addRoutes(new camelJdbc().new MyRouteBuilder());

        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        context.stop();
    }

    class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        public void configure() {
            from("timer://Timer?period=60000")
            .setBody(constant("select * from employee"))
            .to("jdbc:myDataSource")
            .split(body())
            .choice()
            .when(body().convertToString().contains("roll=10"))
            .setBody(constant(///////What SQL command should I write here????/////))
            .to("jdbc:myDataSource1")
            .otherwise()
            .to("stream:out");
        }
    }

    private static DataSource setupDataSource(String connectURI) {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("");
        ds.setUrl(connectURI);
        return ds;
    }

    private static DataSource setupDataSource1(String connectURI1) {
        BasicDataSource ds1 = new BasicDataSource();
        ds1.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds1.setUsername("root");
        ds1.setPassword("");
        ds1.setUrl(connectURI1);
        return ds1;
    }
}
```

Guys I am not sure what SQL command should I give in the "to" endpoint. Also I have written this code by my own as I am not getting much materiel on internet so I am not even sure whether its even remotely correct or I am totally out of track. Kindly help me figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [camel-jdb](http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html)c component expects SQL text, so the body should contain an insert statement...

so, you need to parse the results from your select stmt which returns `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`...the split() gets you to `HashMap<String, Object>`, so you can extract those map values using [camel-simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html)...

something like this...

```
.setBody(simple("insert into employee values('${body[id]','${body[name]}')"))
```

Comment: great, I update the http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html page with a clear example of doing this...