# apache-camel - how to access column value of a result set

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel route which does a select query from a table, then split the rows, then does something and then update rows of the same table.

```
  <route>
<from uri="sql:SELECT ID,NAME,ADDRESS FROM TABLE WHERE SOMECOLUMN = 'Z'?consumer.delay=10000"/>
<split id="_split1">
  <simple>body</simple>
  <!-- DO SOMETHING -->
  <to uri="sql:UPDATE TABLE WHERE ID = {ID FROM DE RESULT QUERY}?consumer.delay=10000"/>
</split>
```

How can i access to that column value without java objects?

Comment: sorry .. i found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27199140/6755290 ... must i delete my question ?

Comment: Well you can if you want but it is not an exact duplicate of the other questions. Alternatively answer your own question if you want and expand the other answer a bit with what you learned.